# Retrieving clean plain text from Wikipedia

Tags: python, text-to-speech, wikipedia, plaintext

I have a text to speech reader which I like to use because it helps with my dyslexia. I want it to read Wikipedia pages for me. I can use readability to clean up the page somewhat, but it still has all the citations like this[1], in the text and between sections, it says "edit" and "citation needed" a lot. It also says things like "Main article: Example", and it still contains picture captions.

I don't really want to have to download a whole dump and parse it as that seems like too much. What I'd really like is to be able to see the pages in "reading mode" where they are like they would be in a reading book. I do know a bit of Python, so I would be ok with writing a scraper which could take the url, download the data and then parse it. However, I am not sure how to get started.

The TTS program I have reads things which are copied from the clipboard, so if the input were a URL and the program copied the text to the clipboard that would be amazing.

Where would I start with this sort of thing? Could you possibly outline the steps I would need to do? Are there any packages out there that can already do this?

-- Edit

This is what I have so far, it works alright (sorry for how horrible my code is)

```
import wikipedia
article=wikipedia.page("USA")
content = article.content.encode('utf8')
content1 = content.replace("=","")
content2 = content1.replace("edit","")
content2 = content1.replace("/","")
import string
content3 = filter(lambda x: x in string.printable, content2)
print content3

import pyperclip
pyperclip.copy(content3)
```

Comment: *"I don't really want to have to download a whole dump and parse it"* and *"I would be ok with writing a scraper which could take the url, download the data and then parse it"* are contradictionary statements

Comment: You may want to look into using [Wikipedia's API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page) and use the plain text variant of one of the available output formats. [Sandbox Example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=query&prop=extracts&format=json&explaintext=&exsectionformat=plain&titles=Albert%20Einstein) (click "Make Request" on that page)

Answer (score 2):

I believe the [Wikipedia Python library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wikipedia/) is what you're looking for.

```
import wikipedia
article=wikipedia.page('"Hello, World!" program')
article.content
```